# How do I add validations to my textfields with the intention to redirect them to another screen if they are validated?

Tags: flutter, validation

I am expected to solve this problem:
Create a username and a password textfield and have your user input data into them. If there's data inputted and they click a button, they will be redirected to another screen. Otherwise, they won't be able to.

This is currently what I have coded in my initial screen:

```
child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  HomeLogo(imageName: 'assets/images/logo1.jpg'),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50)),
                  CommonTextField(
                      text: 'Username',
                      controller: _usernameTextController,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hint: 'Please enter your username.'),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                  CommonTextField(
                      text: 'Password',
                      controller: _passwordTextController,
                      icon: Icons.password,
                      hint: 'Please enter your password.'),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
               new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton (
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(120,58),primary: Colors.blue),
                    onPressed: (){}, child: Text('CLEAR'),),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38)),
                  SignInButton(isSignIn: true, context: context, onTap: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => HomeScreen(email: _usernameTextController.text,)));
                  }),
                    ],
                  ),
```

```
class CommonTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final IconData icon;
  final String hint;

  const CommonTextField(
      {Key? key,
        required this.text,
        required this.controller,
        required this.icon,
        required this.hint})
        : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          suffixIcon: Icon(icon),
          labelText: text,
          hintText: hint,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using textfields as these are the only ones I am familiar with. If there's a way to achieve what I need to do in an easier format, I'd greatly appreciate it if you teach me what I could do! Thanks!

Comment: user `Form` widget and use the global key. you can see the example in the link here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Form` widget with `GlobalKey<FormState>()` to achieve this

- wrap your widget with Form widget and make sure that Form is the parent for all `TextFormField/CommonTextField`
- create GlobalKey() and pass it to the Form `Form(key: formKey,...)`
- add `final String? Function(String?)? validator;` to `CommonTextField` class and pass it into TextFormField `TextFormField(validator: validator,....)`
- pass validator to the CommonTextField widget

  ```
     CommonTextField(
         validator: (value) {
           if (value!.length < 6) return "min 6 char";
           if (value.toLowerCase() == value)
             return "use upper and lower case letter";
           // .... more condition or you may use regexp
         },)
  ```
- validate using formKey when the button pressed

  ```
     ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: () {
         if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
           // validate
           // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute ...
         } else {
           //  wrong data
         }
       },
       child: Text('Singin'),
     ),
  ```

complete code example

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CommonTextField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.length < 6) return "min 6 char";
                if (value.toLowerCase() == value)
                  return "use upper and lower case letter";
                // .... more condition or you may use regexp
              },
              text: 'Password',
              controller: TextEditingController(),
              icon: Icons.password,
              hint: 'Please enter your password.'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // validate
                // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute ...
              } else {
                //  wrong data
              }
            },
            child: Text('Singin'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CommonTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final IconData icon;
  final String hint;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;

  const CommonTextField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      required this.controller,
      required this.icon,
      this.validator,
      required this.hint})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: validator,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          suffixIcon: Icon(icon),
          labelText: text,
          hintText: hint,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```